# which is better for query processing tool in hbase and hive

Tags: hbase

Hello I am new in hbase . I want to use hbase for query processing in my hadoop cluster, any one please tell me which one is better in hive and hbase for query processing

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the *database* you are working on.`Hive` queries **SQL** where as `Hbase` can be used for **NOSQL** *database*. It is a good choice to use both. `Hive` can be used for analytical queries while `HBase`for real-time querying.

Comment: Hello vasanth . I am moving my oracle database to hdfs for query processing and for analytic  we want to use tableau . so please tell me which one is better.

Comment: @reeshu patel You are not specific on your question.but,since you mentioned you are using oracle.. you may choose hive.